# Why are Set Cardinality and Absolute Value denoted the same way?

Tags: soft-question, notation

When we have a set $A$, it is conventional to denote the cardinality of $A$ as $|A|$. When we have some number $n$, it is conventional to denote the absolute value of said number as $|n|$.

My question is whether there's any 'deeper' reason for this: is there some mathematical connection between the two concepts that explains why the two operators are denoted the same way?

Answer (score 3):

We tend to use bars to denote some concept of 'size', whether it be cardinality, absolute value, determinant, or a norm. For cardinality, other accepted notations include $\#A$ and $card(A)$.

Comment: Also Cantor's notation for cardinality, $\overline{\overline A}$.

Comment: @bof I think that notation might have fallen out of favour with modern authors, but yes that's another alternative :).

Comment: Fair enough - I usually use $\#(A)$ to denote set cardinality to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

For a finite set S, its cardinality (being a non-negative integer) is sometimes denoted by S, or at least it was when I was in primary (junior) school in the 1970's.